# Why does the upper class of Egypt dislike Hamas?

Tags: egypt

The Palestinian Islamic resistance group, which is popularly known as ‘Hamas’, is originally rooted from Muslim brotherhood. Though brotherhood was banned by the government of Egypt, but it has spread its faith and principle successfully to the other Arabic countries. After talking with some Egyptian people, I know that they show their compassion to Hamas and I think that most of Egyptian people have the same feeling. But why the upper class, especially the Egyptian government dislikes Hamas?

Comment: "it has spread its faith and principle successfully to the other Arabic countries" and "the upper class dislikes the Hamas" are statements which need to be proven (otherwise your question will be considered as opinion based, see the site tour.). You need for instance a poll that shows the attitude of rich people towards the Hamas is different. You don't need it for the government, though, we can check public declarations.

Comment: Are you suggesting that they specifically dislike Hamas, or that they dislike the Muslim Brotherhood and Hamas as its offspring?

Answer (score 3):

> Most of Egyptian people have the same feeling. Why does the upper class dislike hamas ?

Most egyptians, or at least a lot of them, have a negative view of the hamas. The PEW research center asked for this only among muslims (90 % of the general population), and found out that [only 49%](http://www.pewglobal.org/2010/12/02/muslims-around-the-world-divided-on-hamas-and-hezbollah/) had a favorable view of the hamas. 51 % of muslims, to which some of the non-muslims can probably be added, is nothing near an "upper class". The poll is a little old, 2010, but it is unlikely that the results would have a major shift.

> Why does the egyptian government dislike the hamas ?

You stated it, the hamas originated from the muslim brotherhood which is forbidden in Egypt.

However, it may not be like this very long anymore. [This article](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20170130-hamas-and-al-sisi-a-new-page/) states that the government may change its attitude towards the hamas.